# Does calling createUpload in aws devicefarm actually upload the file?

Tags: aws-device-farm

I'm switching from using the aws cli to the sdk so I can make some nicer scripts but it seems i'd still have to curl after calling createUpload. Is there a nicer way of doing this? Or something that does the upload in one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createUpload` just creates a S3 bucket with a pre-signed key, you still have to do a `put` to the bucket to actually upload anything, I don't think there is a single command that combines the two.

This is how I do it in Python:

```
upload = device_farm.create_upload(projectArn=project['arn'], name='spec.yml', type='APPIUM_WEB_PYTHON_TEST_SPEC')
response = requests.put(upload['upload']['url'], data= open('testspec.yml', 'rb'), headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

Comment: Is it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html that I need? I get the long url back in the create upload response. Where to put that? If there's a guide that combines the two would be cool

Comment: I meant HTTP PUT, this is how I do it in Python: 
upload = device_farm.create_upload(projectArn='ARN ..)
response = requests.put(upload['upload']['url'], data= open('testspec.yml', 'rb'), headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})